# python - def - else statement not working

Tags: python, if-statement, function

Okay, I'm very new to this, wrote a simple unit conversion program from miles to km however my `else` statement doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what wrote:

```
def kmtoMil(dist):
   return (dist / 0.62137)

def miltoKm(dist):
   return (dist * 0.62137)

def convert(dist, toScale):
   if toScale.lower() == "K":
      return miltoKm(dist)
   else:
      return kmtoMil(dist)

print ("Enter a distance: ")
dist = int(input())
print ("Choose unit to convert to: ")
scale = input()
convertDist = convert(dist, scale)
print (dist, convertDist, scale)
```

It seems to apply the first def (I can interchange the kmtoMil & miltoKm on line 9 & 11 and 9 seems to take) but not the second. I hope that makes sense.

I'm thinking something wrong with the `else:` statement...but not sure and curious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `toScale.lower() == "K"` --> Take the letter, make it lower case, and compare it to capital K. This will always be false.

Answer (score 3):

you have a bug dude... its pretty simple

```
if toScale.lower() == "K":
SHOULD BE
if toScale.lower() == "k":
```

but try this:

```
if toScale in ["K", "k"]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `lower()` but comparing with an upper-case character. So consider using `if toScale.lower() == "k":` or `if toScale.upper() == "K":`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `toScale.lower() == "K"` to `toScale.lower() == "k"`